# Minimist Github page doesn't exit

Tags: npm

Apparently one of my repos has a vulnerable package, but when I look it up it doesn't exist. Any ideas?

https://github.com/substack/minimist

https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

I think the author's GitHub account was hidden, deleted, or suspended.

## Reasoning

The page https://github.com/substack also leads to a 404.

I found [a July 2022 snapshot of the minimist github repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20220728060622/https://github.com/substack/minimist) on archive.org. It looks like there were 43 open issues and 28 open PRs at that point, and the latest commit was 4 months prior, in March 2022. While 4 months isn't a long time, the number of open items may indicate that the maintainer didn't have enough time to keep working on the project. This is pure speculation on my point - I haven't tried to make contact or anything like that.

While [the NPM unpublish policy](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish) and [the NPM acceptable use policy](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/conduct#acceptable-use) define scenarios where the package could be removed entirely from NPM, it doesn't even appear to be deprecated. The package page is still up on the website.

[GitHub policy](https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/github-terms/github-community-guidelines#what-happens-if-someone-violates-githubs-policies) allows for suspending or hiding a user account, or the user could easily have chosen to delete it for whatever reason.

## My recommendation

Both the repository's README and https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-MINIMIST-2429795 indicate that 1.2.6 fixes that security issue, so I would force that in your lockfile as soon as you have the bandwidth. If this is a transitive dependency, it may also be worth warning the maintainers of whichever package directly depends on `minimist`.

You do have another option, since the code is licensed under an MIT license. You (and/or anyone else who is interested) can choose to fork the code and build a fully-compatible replacement version of the package. Of course, you can also choose to switch to another argument-parsing library.